# Generate a PDF using node, pdfkit and fontawesome?

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, pdfkit, fontawesome-4.4.0

I'm running a node server and wanted to add some icons to a dynamically created PDF using PDFkit - so I installed fontawesome `npm install fontawesome` and required it in the .js file creating the pdf `var fa = require('fontawesome');`

I then tried to use the icons with PDFKit:

`doc.fontSize(40).fill('black').text(fa('bath'), 160, 80);`

But, I don't see a `bath` icon - just two jibberish symbols in its place.

What do I have to do to render the fa icons? This is a server-side script without a front end, and is run using a cron that pings a oracle view for dynamic information as part of a daily email. (So, I'm not using any css or html to create the document)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the fontawesome font and copy pasting the icon from fontawesome

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var doc = new PDFDocument();

doc.registerFont('Fontawesome', 'fonts/fontawesome-solid-900.ttf')

doc.font('Fontawesome')
   .fontSize(20)
   .text('', 10, 10);

doc.write('out.pdf');
```

You can copy paste font icons from here https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

Comment: I tried the above code I am getting this error  , I  need to  print few icons on my pdf

"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'fonts/fontawesome-solid-900.ttf'" 
@Niels van Rijn